# spark assign column name for withColumn function from variable fields

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some json data like below, I need to create new columns based on the some Jason values

```json
{ "start": "1234567679", "test": ["abc"], "value": 324, "end": "1234567689" }

{ "start": "1234567679", "test": ["xyz"], "value": "Near", "end": "1234567689"}

{ "start": "1234568679", "test": ["pqr"], "value": ["Attr"," "], "end":"1234568679"}  

{ "start": "1234568997", "test": ["mno"], "value": ["{\"key\": \"1\", \"value\": [\"789\"]}" ], "end": "1234568999"}
```

above is the json example

I want to create a column like below

```
 start      abc     xyz    pqr     mno    end
 1234567679 324     null   null    null   1234567689
 1234567889 null    Near   null    null   1234567989
 1234568679 null    null   attr    null   1234568679
 1234568997 null    null   null    789    1234568999
```

```scala
def getValue1(s1: Seq[String], v: String) = {
     if (s1(0)=="abc"))  v else null
} 
 
def getValue2(s1: Seq[String], v: String) = {
    if (s1(0)=="xyz"))  v else null
}  

val df = spark.read.json("path to json")

val tdf = df.withColumn("abc",getValue1($"test", $"value")).withColumn("xyz",getValue2($"test", $"value"))
```

But this  i dont want to use because my test values are more, I want some function  do something like this

```scala
def getColumnname(s1: Seq[String]) = {
    return s1(0)
}  

val tdf = df.withColumn(getColumnname($"test"),$"value"))
```

is it good idea to change the values to columns, I want like this because I need to apply this on some Machine learning code which needs plain columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use pivot operations to do such things. Assuming you always have one item in your array for `test` column, here is the simpler solution;

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = sqlContext.read.json("<yourPath>")
df.withColumn("test", $"test".getItem(0)).groupBy($"start", $"end").pivot("test").agg(first("value")).show
+----------+----------+----+----+
|     start|       end| abc| xyz|
+----------+----------+----+----+
|1234567679|1234567689| 324|null|
|1234567889|1234567689|null| 789|
+----------+----------+----+----+
```

If you have multiple values in `test` column, you can also use `explode` function;

```
df.withColumn("test", explode($"test")).groupBy($"start", $"end").pivot("test").agg(first("value")).show
```

For more information:

- [Spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset@pivot(pivotColumn:String,values:Seq[Any]):org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset)
- [Databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html)
- [Medium blog](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/working-with-spark-arraytype-and-maptype-columns-4d85f3c8b2b3)

I hope it helps!

### Update I

Based on your comments and updated question, here is the solution that you need to follow. I have ***intentionally*** seperated all operations, so you can easily understand what you need to do for further improvements;

```
df.withColumn("value", regexp_replace($"value", "\\[", "")). //1
   withColumn("value", regexp_replace($"value", "\\]", "")). //2
   withColumn("value", split($"value", "\\,")).              //3
   withColumn("test", explode($"test")).                     //4
   withColumn("value", explode($"value")).                   //5
   withColumn("value", regexp_replace($"value", " +", "")).  //6
   filter($"value" !== "").                                  //7
   groupBy($"start", $"end").pivot("test").                  //8
   agg(first("value")).show                                  //9
```

- When you read such json files, it will give you a data frame which has `value` column with `StringType`. You can not directly convert `StringType` to `ArrayType`, so you need to do some kind of tricks like in the lines 1, 2, 3  to convert it into `ArrayType`. **You can do these operations in one line or with just one regular expression or defining udf. It is all up to you,** I'm just trying to show you the abilities of Apache Spark.
- Now you have `value` column with `ArrayType`. Explode this column in line 5 as we did in line 4 for `test` column. Then apply your pivoting operations.

Comment: hi, there is one more strange fields observred in my data, value filed is not always int, it sometimes string, Array etc  .. { "start": "1234567679", "test": ["abc"], "value": 324, "end": "1234567689" }
{ "start": "1234567679", "test": ["xyz"], "value": "Near", "end": "1234567689"}
{ "start": "1234567679", "test": ["pqr"], "value": ["List"], "end": "1234567689"}

Comment: Hi, I found one more type in value field which is in json, I want to extract only the value field from the json